# Can Cisco ASA PBR route to specific IP/port?

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa

I am working on setting up PBR on our ASA-5505, and was trying to figure out if this scenario is possible.

1. Traffic coming in via one public externa IP on port 443.
2. ASA identify traffic via ACL and uses PBR to route traffic using next-hop IP

Question, is it possible to specify a destination port in step 2?

Basically I want so setup 2 PBR where step 1 is the same, but 2 would route traffic to same IP but different ports.

Disclaimer: I normally do not work with this kind of stuff. Nothing can go wrong. :-)

Comment: PBR works as extended ACL so in theory a port-based rule should work. However, I have not practically tested this.

Comment: @Overmind The ACL is for identifying what source to route (if I got it correct), and I want to specify a port for the destination, but all examples I found only specify an IP as next-hop hence I start to think you can specify anything else for destination.